# Change color of Rectangle Shape from a thread different than GUI Thread in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I need to change the color of a `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.RectangleShape` from another thread than the one where it was created. For other controls like a button I am doing the following:

```
if (button.InvokeRequired)
{
    button.Invoke((System.Action)(() =>
    {
        button.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }));
}
else
{
   button.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

The problem is `InvokeRequired` or `Invoke` are not available for `RectangleShape`.

***What can I do instead?***

Comment: Are you calling this code from a `Form`?

Comment: this code is been called from a Form, inside a Method than runs in a particular Thread

Comment: `shape.Parent.InvokeRequired` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shape will go in `ShapeContainer` which can be found in `shape.Parent` property. So you can use `shape.Parent.InvokeRequired`.

Also following the DRY principle:

```
var action = (System.Action)(() =>
{
    shape.BackColor = Color.Red;
};

if (shape.Parent.InvokeRequired)
{
    shape.Parent.Invoke(action);
}
else
{
   action();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.shape.parent.aspx) property of `RectangleShape`:

```
if (shape.Parent.InvokeRequired)
{
    shape.Parent.Invoke((System.Action)(() =>
    {
        button.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }));
}
else
{
   button.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: FWIW: This will lead to `InvalidOperationException` when `Form` is created in one thread and `Shape.Parent` in another thread (If `Shape.Parent` is not added to `Form`). 99.99% of the time this is not a problem because `Owner` will be same `Thread` which is MainThread.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You're right, i edited the answer to include the `Parent` property only.